# Retrieving profile information of members of a Facebook closed group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I belong to a closed Facebook group. I would like to retrieve information such as (email, location etc) of the members of the group to integrate with a mobile app.

Using the Graph API and currently testing with the Graph explorer I am able to view the list of members, along with thier name, of the group. But I am not able to view infomation such as email, location etc even though I have selected it be part of the response.

-Do I need additional permissions to view additional information of the members?
-Do I need a facebook app to achieve this? If so how will it interact with the mobile app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

group_id/members endpoint returns a list of members with the attributes - id, name, administrator. If you want to get further details about these members, you will have to query graph API again for each of these members.

Comment: can you tell me, what is that ID? because it's not the same ID that can be found in user profile. Do you know how to get user id and username for all users in group ? thanks